# How to change the text color of an xamdatagrid?

Tags: c#, xaml, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I was wondering how you can change the text color of an xamdatagrid. I'm not talking about the xaml part. I want to know if you can change the color of the text within the c# part of the code. 
I would also like to see an example of the c# and the xaml code to see how this works.
Thank you

Comment: Do you want to change the datagrid rows forground color?

Comment: I want to change the color of the text if that's what you mean

Comment: whether you do this in C# or XAML you need to use a style targeting the CellValuePresenter.  there is examples of changing the text color in the help: http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WPF/2011.2/CLR4.0/html/xamDataGrid_CellValuePesenterStyleSelector_Reevaluated.html

Comment: you may also be interested in the following blog post: http://mytorrey.com/2011/05/08/conditionally-formatting-cells-in-xamdatagrid-2/